# How to get case entities using SOAP

Tags: soap-api, case, soap

I've managed to get account data, but now I'm trying to get a case object - any case object - with no luck and, apparently, no example code.

To get accounts, I'm using this code:

```
$accounts = $mySforceConnection->search('FIND {Valid Account Name} IN Name FIELDS RETURNING ACCOUNT(ID)');
```

However, similar code doesn't work:

```
$cases = $mySforceConnection->search('FIND {Valid Case ID} IN CaseId FIELDS RETURNING Case(Subject)');
```

The Force Explorer tool returns results no problem and shows me these fields, but my code, when run, returns

```
[message:protected] => MALFORMED_SEARCH: Invalid IN fields group: CaseId
```

This happens no matter what fields I use and I know that the fields I'm testing are valid. I've tried using the associated account, the subject, different forms of ID... nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the WSDL you're using.

Comment: There is no field group called CaseId. Try usig $cases = $mySforceConnection->search('FIND {Valid Case ID} IN Id FIELDS RETURNING Case(Subject)');

Comment: @VigneshwaranG, I tried that, below is the sanitized output:

`FIND {5008**********} IN Id FIELDS RETURNING Case(Subject)
SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => MALFORMED_SEARCH: Invalid IN fields group: Id
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /var/www/html/Forcetk/soapclient/SforceBaseClient.php
    [line:protected] => 876
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
`
... etc

Answer (score 0):

After bashing my head against the wall quite a bit, I found a query that returned a case. From that I'll be able to explore how the structure is built.

`FIND {Valid} IN Name FIELDS RETURNING CASE(AccountID)`

I did look at every page I could find with the letters 'WSDL', but found very little that made sense. As is, I'll work with what I do have and leave this here for future reference.